# keyup/Keydown event for tab key is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using a keyup event for  tab. But fore some reason the code only runs with other keycodes like 38,40,13 . By pressing tab it just does the default tab action and ignores the code. Please help.

```
dom.live('keyup', function (e) {
    var newDom = $(this);
    var suggestionpageCount = newDom.attr('data-counter');
      if ((e.keyCode == 38) || (e.keyCode == 40)) {
        ..some code here

    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        ..some code here
    }
else if (e.keycode == 9) {
        ..some code here
    }
```

I also tried to add it on    dom.live('keydown', function (e) 
but its not working too..

So I noticed that when the cursor is focused on textbox, keyup/keydown function doesn't worked for tab key. do you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: 'keydown' also work with "Sridhar R" answer

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is listen to the keydown on the parent and [delegate](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) the event downwards, the tab key's default behaviour is to change element focus meaning the keyup happens on the next element on the page.

```js
$('textarea').parent().on('keydown', 'textarea', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Tab key pressed');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

On a separate note, try using a `switch` instead of lots of `if/else` statements. They're easier to read and generally out-perform if's/else's